# Correct progress of an offline download with AVAssetDownloadURLSession

Tags: ios, download, avfoundation, offline, progress

I'm downloading offline video thanks to AVAssetDownloadURLSession, AVAssetDownloadDelegate for iOS 11 using makeAssetDownloadTask(...) and aggregateAssetDownloadTask(...) method.

Everything works but I just want to let the users know the progress of each download as accurately as possible.

To do so I use:

```
- urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didLoad timeRange: CMTimeRange, totalTimeRangesLoaded loadedTimeRanges: [NSValue], timeRangeExpectedToLoad: CMTimeRange)

- urlSession(_ session: URLSession, aggregateAssetDownloadTask: AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask, didLoad timeRange: CMTimeRange, totalTimeRangesLoaded loadedTimeRanges: [NSValue], timeRangeExpectedToLoad: CMTimeRange, for mediaSelection: AVMediaSelection)
```

With these methods I'm able to calculate the download progress of the video and each tracks (audio/subtitle) separately. So I assume the video is 70% of the download and for the tracks it's 30% divided by the number of tracks.
I store the download progress of each items in a temporary dictionary (multiplied by their ratio) and I add each progress for a download to have a global representation.

In the end it works fine but it's not as smooth as expected. For example I spend 3min to download the content but if the weight of a track is light, the progress will jump from 70% to 85% in 1sec (if I have 2 tracks to download) and slow down right after.
I would like to have a global progress.

I definitely not happy with this solution but I currently did not find another solution.

Do some of you have any ideas/solutions?

Thanks guys

Comment: I'd love to see your code for how you're doing this, I'm having the same problem and your solution is better than what i have now.

Comment: Sadly I did not find a solution yet because I do not have enough time to find a better way to do it.

Comment: Exactly the same problem too :( So sad they didn't add global progress for it. @Guillaume can you please share your calculation as a reference?

Comment: @mgyky Actually, I did leave the company, also there choose to use the SDK of  another company which is not open source, so I'm sorry but I can't tell you.

But, before that what I did was an approximation. I had 1 video file and 4 tracks. So made a calculation with video = 80% and 4 tracks = 20%. It works correctly but for some download it could end up very quickly due to the side of the video and the size and type of the tracks.

Comment: @Guillaume thank you for the quick answer :) Actually, I watch WWDC 2020 Discover how to download and play HLS offline session, and the presenter says exactly the same thing. Anyway, before starting that part of code I want to see an example :) My tracks are dynamic, some times 2 sound, 2 subtitles, sometimes only 1 sound, and that's all. I'll figure it out. Thank you, and wish you the best in a new position.

Comment: @Guillaume, I shared my solution a while ago, If you find it useful kindly sign as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

First of all, this is just my case, you should update the method for your needs.

In my scenario, as a **most complicated array example** I have something like this:

```
[English(soun),Turkish(soun),English(sbtl),Turkish(sbtl)]
```

We'll give **80 percent for Audio all audios**, and **20 percent for all subtitles**.

The total calculation formula must be something like this:

```
(100*(0,80/2))+(100*(0,80/2))+(100*(0,20/2))+(100(0,20/2))
```

We need an enum for representing [AVMediaType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmediatype):

```
// AVMediaType
enum MediaType: String {
    // Sound
    case soun
        
    // Subtitle
    case sbtl
      
    // Closed Caption
    // case clcp // Removed for simplifying the example.
}
```

Also, we'll need a Dictionary to handle Asset Download Progress:

```
var totalDownloadProgressForAsset = [String: Double]()
```

And here is the method:

```
public func getTotalProgress() -> Double {
    var result = 0.0
    let soundMultiplier          = 0.80
    let subtitleMultiplier       = 0.20
    var soundCount = 0
    var subtitleCount  = 0
    
    for (key, _) in totalDownloadProgressForAsset {
        let mediaTypeKey = String(key.suffix(4))
        let type = MediaType(rawValue: mediaTypeKey)
        
        switch type {
        case .soun:
            soundCount += 1
        case .sbtl:
            subtitleCount += 1
        case .none:
            break
        }
    }
                    
    for (key, value) in totalDownloadProgressForAsset {
        let mediaTypeKey = String(key.suffix(4))
        let type = MediaType(rawValue: mediaTypeKey)
        
        switch type {
        case .soun:
            result += Double(value*(soundMultiplier/Double(soundCount)))
        case .sbtl:
            result += Double(value*(subtitleMultiplier/Double(subtitleCount)))
        case .none:
            break
        }
    }
    
    return result
}
```

Of course, we can write this differently, this is just for example.

Feel free to ask anything about it.

Comment: Hi mgykj, how are you able to determine, what type each AVMediaSelection from allMediaSelections is? I also have multiple audios and subtitles, that I am downloading, but I cannot determine, type for each, so I'm not able to correctly multiply value. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Arijan, you can determine with let type = MediaType(rawValue: mediaTypeKey), and then you can separate each with switch type. Get String representation of media type (vide, soun, sbtl, etc.) Check the switch blocks in my answer.

Comment: Hello, I'm currently working on a video download feature, and trying to update the progress on a multiple MediaSelection download. 
I would have thought that the first track to be downloaded would be a track of type MediaVideo, but it seems that I only download audio and subtitle, is it the same for you? as I see you only account for audio and subtitle in your code example.

Comment: Hi mgyky,  i'm using AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask,  from urlSession:aggregateAssetDownloadTask:didLoad:totalTimeRangesLoaded:timeRangeExpectedToLoad:for    i get  "mediaSelection", but im not able to distinguish what type of media (mediaTypeKey) is this delegate being called for, how did you solve this?

Comment: If you didn't, you need a global activeDownloadsMap to follow tasks, otherwise, you can't be sure. 

/// Internal map of AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask to its corresponding Asset.
    fileprivate var activeDownloadsMap = [AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask: Asset]()